# Parallell unit testing in C# when using TCP listeners?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, msbuild

So I have two test classes, both which need to set up a server listening on a TCP-port and one or more clients connecting.

Now to make sure they are using free ports and not using the same ports (as we run our tests parallell) I've used the following code (stolen straight up from stackoverflow):

```
        IPGlobalProperties ipGlobalProperties = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties();
        TcpConnectionInformation[] tcpConnInfoArray = ipGlobalProperties.GetActiveTcpConnections();

        foreach (TcpConnectionInformation tcpi in tcpConnInfoArray)
        {
            m_OccupiedPorts.Add(tcpi.LocalEndPoint.Port);
        }

        while (m_OccupiedPorts.Contains(m_Port))
        {
            m_Port++;
        }
```

Assuming no other application occupies any ports between I get the info and create my tcp-listener, it still seems to me that 2 tests from the same class could end up on the same port?

This I could probably solve by having a static lock on the class but I dont know if this is really good code practice?

Second question though is that I have completely seperate class doing the same setup and using the same code and Im not sure if both classes can run their code at the same time, or if running unit tests parallelly only does so on tests in the same class?

If not, is there any way to keep have a mutual lock between two different test classes?

Both classes are part of the same assembly if that makes any difference.

Hope my questions werent to confusing and any help or pointing in a direction of some resources explaining the order/context unit tests gets run with MSBUILD would be appreciated

EDIT: Both test-classes uses a helper class and my first thought was for the other classes to query the ports from that class, but I was very unsure about how and when a (static field) helper-class gets instanciated regarding to the two other classes.

Comment: It think if tests are running parallel, depends on the unit testing framework and the test runner. In my eye the easiest way is to implement a locker on the posted method. 
Also I would recommend not to use real tcp connections, but you should mock it. If necessary you can unit test the tcp connection anyway (for example if you use a wrapper for the tcp connection)

Comment: Well my real problem is that there are more than one test-class calling this method, so even if the lock is static, Im not completely sure it will be the same instance for both classes (even though theyre both in the same assembly).

I like the idea about mocking the TCP part though, I might actually go down that route.